# How to design a Circuit that can turn a LED ON depending on the input voltage

Tags: led, power-electronics, device

I have three LEDs, and I want to turn the first LED ON if the input voltage is 4V , I want to turn the first and second LED ON if the input voltage is 8V and so on.

Is it possible to do without any microcontroller? I want just microeletronics devices working on it.

Comment: What is the voltage is 4.01V - does the LED stop illuminating? What is the range of voltages around 4V and 8V that the leds must switch on? Or do you mean turn on if greater than?

Comment: Yes, greater than 4V and so on

Answer (score 6):

The classic [LM3914](http://www.ti.com/product/lm3914) contains multiple comparator stages that are used to drive LEDs in either a bar or a dot configuration. Using a 4:1 voltage divider will let you sense voltages of up to 44V given a supply voltage of at least 12V.

[Designing a Li-Ion Battery Gauge with the LM3914 - EEVblog #204](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIKGvHjDQHs)

Comment: There's also numerous basic circuits for this sort of thing using op-amps or transistors if you google -In Forrest M Mims III's excellent books he has some good ones using LM324 or similar. But LM3914 is by far the easiest answer.

Comment: Who or what is this "alot" and why am I helping them?